# How to clear search history in glogg?

Tags: cleanup

I am using glogg to scan log files, but since the installation all the searches are saved somewhere and it is getting huge and huge.

Using Bleachbit to clean the system isn't helpful for glogg until now and everytime I make a log search the history is saved somewhere for glogg.

Comment: Even if this is Ubuntu forum, and the answer below explains it for Ubuntu, I am just adding a comment for the history file location on Windows: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\glogg\glogg.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Find glogg.conf in your home dir.

It contains all your search history under the [SavedSearches] tag.